# How to remove something from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, relationship

I have a Rails app with a User.rb model that has a many to many relationship with a Practice.rb model (which might be a bad name for the model) For example, a user might work in several different practice areas (such as 'karate' and 'judo'), which I seeded the database with. There is a situation where I wish to reduce the number of practices a user has (user has a maximum of two) and therefore I do this inside a method in one of the models in order to remove the second practice

```
      if user.practices.size > 1
        user.practices[1].destroy
      end
```

However, the result is that it's not only removing that practice (for example, 'karate') from the `user.practices`, but destroying the practice out of existence, such that 'karate' is no longer listed in the available practices for anyone. If I do `Practice.all` 'karate' will not appear.

The same thing happens if I use `'delete'` instead of `'destroy.'`

user.practices yields a CollectionProxy

What is the proper way to remove it from the `user.practices` without removing it totally from `Practice.all`

Update

The model set up is like this. Ideally when I remove the practice from the user, the relevant practice_listing would also be deleted.

```
User.rb

has_many :practice_listings
  has_many :practices, through: :practice_listings

Practice.rb
 has_many :practice_listings
  has_many :users, through: :practice_listings

PracticeListing.rb

belongs_to :practice
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: is there a UserPractice model?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott there's a PracticeListing model (see OP) Is the name significant for Rails? I know in some cases (with join tables) it's important that a join model share the name in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove element from array:

```
user.practices.delete(user.practices[2])
```

Or:

```
user.practices.delete_at(2)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a has_many :through with a PracticeListing model (see OP if you can). While your solution works to remove the practice from the `user.practices` will it also delete the relevant PracticeListing?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. One is:

```
 user.practices = user.practices - [user.practices[1]]
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a has_many :through with a PracticeListing model (see OP if you can). While your solution works to remove the practice from the `user.practices` will it also delete the relevant PracticeListing?  Can you show me how?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it should automatically delete the PracticeListing. Why don't you try it out and confirm?

Comment: I did try it and i got unclear results  One time it seemed to, one time it didn't :(. will try again.

Comment: it doesn't delete the associated practice listing

Comment: In that case, rather than deleting from `user.practices`, why don't you delete from `user.practice_listings`?

Comment: doing this (as recommended by the other answer) deletes from both `user.practices.delete(user.practices[2])`